# Consume list of messages from subscription using Spring boot gcp

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

Team,

We are streaming messages from subscription using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub library:

Sample Code:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel inputMessageChannel() {
  return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter inboundChannelAdapter(
    @Qualifier("inputMessageChannel") MessageChannel messageChannel,
    PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
  PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
      new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "project/projectid/subscription");
  adapter.setOutputChannel(messageChannel);
  adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
  adapter.setPayloadType(String.class);
  return adapter;
}


@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
public void messageReceiver(
    String payload,
    @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
//process and store to db table
  message.ack();
}
```

The above approach streams one message at a time and the process is taking time. I am planning to implement the below approach:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
public void messageReceiver(
    String payload,
    @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
//Get input as list of messages
//assign the messages to Executor threadpool and process asynchronously
  message.ack();
}
```

I searched through the article but not getting details on how to consume list of messages.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "pubsubInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10"))
public MessageSource<Object> pubsubAdapter(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    PubSubMessageSource messageSource = new PubSubMessageSource(pubSubTemplate,  "project/projectid/subscription");
    messageSource.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    messageSource.setPayloadType(String.class);
    messageSource.setBlockOnPull(false);
    messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(10);
    return messageSource;
}
```

But not sure how to use it in message receiver. Could you please help me on this.